# 'Is need, should be, have to' which is better approach?

Tags: difference, comparison

I have sentence like this:

> ...set some edge cases where component will throw an error.

and I'm not sure which of these ones is better:

1. There should be...
2. There have to be...
3. There is need to...

I want to say something like "It would be great and very highly recommended but not necessary to do".

Which approach would be more suited?

Comment: Your version #3 is idiomatically unacceptable without an indefinite article before ***need*** - but note that *there **is no need** to do this if the context includes **negation***

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica thanks for your answer. I assume that the sentence `There is need to be...` have no sense at all as well?

Comment: Of those three options, only number 3 works with the rest of the sentence (though it needs an article, as has been pointed out).  We can't say, "There should be set some..." or "There have to be set some..."  However, "There should be some edge cases set" or "There have to be some edge cases set" are both fine.

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit hasty with that comment. As [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+need+to+be%2Cis+a+need+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20need%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20need%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0) shows, there's been a significant shift over recent decades as regards that article before ***need***.